# Solution to switch quickly between different group of windows by keeping their state (position) on macOS

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, productivity

I am using macos/osx now for more than 15 years and I always try to figure out a good way to group windows and persist their position and state so that I can quickly switch between those groups (contexts). What do I mean by that:

**Project1(context):**

- Display 1: Chrome windows with several taps, on the left side of the display
- Display 1: Chrome windows with several taps, on the right side of the display
- Display 2: Terminal app window

**Project2(context):**

- Display 1: Chrome windows with several taps, on the left side of the display
- Display 1: Chrome windows with several taps, on the right side of the display
- Display 2: IDE
- Display2: Terminal window (but different one)

**Goal:** I want to quickly switch between those project so that windows of the other Project are 'hidden'(or moved somewhere out of my sight) and only the windows of the selected Project are displayed. The position of the windows should also be persistent.

There is a [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/400160/solution-to-keep-complete-projects-completely-separate-with-same-user-and-multip) question but it's over 2 years old and no solution.

**Current Solution:**

At the moment I am using multiple desktops where my displays counts as a single desktop so I can switch both at the same time. This way I can order all the windows in each desktop and have one desktop for one context. However there are some issues with that:

- When I close my laptop or go to stand by, all windows appear on my laptop screen
- I also want to have context independent windows (chat f.e.) which means when I am on desktop 2 and want to quickly chat, the desktop switches to the one where the chat app is open.

I looked at [totalspaces](https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/) but it seems like it is not supported anymore and does not work with the lates macos (m1).

I also had a look at [workspaces](https://www.apptorium.com/workspaces) but it lacks in keeping the windows positions persistent and also does not have the capability to switch between workspaces the way I described it above.

I am looking for any possibilities to improve my situation via paid app, free app, scripting or anything else.

Comment: Have you seen/tried the app called [Stay](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/257864/119271)?  I haven’t used it in a while, but it does what you describe.

Comment: thank you, this could solve the issue when going into stand by, but does not solve the issue that when I switch to an app which should not be part of a context but is open in another desktop that everything switches to this desktop

Comment: I tested the app Stay, but for some reason it only restores the windows correctly for 2 of my desktops but not for the third...

Comment: Try [Rectangle Pro](https://rectangleapp.com/pro) ($9.99USD).  I use it for creating snap areas on my multiple displays, but there is an option to configure Application snaps. There is a free version, but I don’t think it has the app snapping.  There is a free trial on the Pro version

Comment: I am using Rectangle Pro, however I would need snap areas for specific windows not application

Comment: Ahh..specific windows of applications.  Sorry I couldn’t assist more.